# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

- I'm using python3.6 in windows7 and django 1.9
- I got this error when i run my code.
- In my code i'm parsing xml data to write a html page.
- I got that some character is unable to encode properly thats why its throwing an error.
- `\u2264` this is the character(less than or equal) which is the root cause of the error.
- My question is how to encode this properly in python3

Detailed Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\EXE\TEMP\cookie\crumbs\views.py", line 1520, in parser
    html_file.write(html_text)
  File "C:\Users\Cookie1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264' in position 389078: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Add some code so that we can pinpoint the exact problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message indicates that you're trying to encode to the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character encoding. That encoding doesn't have a representation of the less than or equal symbol.

```
>>> "\u2264".encode("cp1252")
>>> Traceback... [as above]
```

The answer is to use UTF-8, an unrestricted encoding, instead of Windows-1252, a very restricted encoding.

Your question doesn't include much context, but the line `html_file.write(html_text)` makes me think you're using Python's file protocol. The [documentation for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) shows how to set the encoding, e.g.

```
html_file = open("file.html", mode="w", encoding="utf8")
```

Note that "the default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)", which is why you're getting Windows-1252 on Windows 7.